# Primefaces tabbing focuses inside unopened sidebar

Tags: primefaces, accessibility

I have created a side menubar using the `p:sidebar` component. My problem is with accessibility. Using the tab key to navigate the page loses focus inside the unopened `p:sidebar` component. Meaning that when i navigate trough the page using the tab key, the focus goes inside the unopened `p:sidebar`, focus should only appear when the sidebar is open. How to correctly implement tab focus to the component and it's content? Also the xhtml included the `p:sidebar` contains `p:link` components that doesn't get tab focus at all when the `p:sidebar` is open.

My `p:sidebar` component:

```
        <p:sidebar  widgetVar="fssidebar" fullScreen="true" styleClass="ws-sidebar" onShow="document.getElementById('menuForm:foliLink').focus()" onHide="sidebarhide()">
          <p:outputPanel id="menuPanel" styleClass="" style="float: left;">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
          </p:outputPanel>
        </p:sidebar>
```

My menu.xhtml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <p:outputPanel id="menupanel">
    <h:commandButton value="X" style="color:white" onclick="sidebarhide();" class="close" pt:aria-label="#{acc['header.closemenu']}" tabindex="0"/>
    <h:form>
      <p:remoteCommand name="sidebarhide" update="@all" global="false"/>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="menuForm" style="float: left;">
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:link value="Link to my page" href="https://www.mypage.com" target="_blank" tabindex="0"/>
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:link value="Main Menu" href="#{ui['main.menu.url']}" target="_blank" tabindex="0" onkeydown="if(event.key==='Tab'){PF('myInplace').display.trigger('click');event.preventDefault();}"/>
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandLink value="Menu Item 1" action="loading?faces-redirect=true" global="false" tabindex="0"/>
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandLink value="Menu Item 2" action="profile?faces-redirect=true" styleClass="ws-menulink ws-font" global="false" tabindex="0"/>
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandLink value="Menu Item 3" action="emv?faces-redirect=true" global="false" tabindex="0"/>        
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:link value="Menu Item 4" href="www.something.com" target="_blank" tabindex="0"/>        
      </p:outputPanel>
      <p:outputPanel>
        <p:link value="Menu Item 5" href="www.something.com" target="_blank" tabindex="0"/>        
      </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: This is not a question, it is an issue report. Please report issues at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues

Comment: You can in your `onhide` and `onshow` JavaScript somehow add a CSS class that makes that component not navigable or sets all the tabindexes to -1.  There has to be a clever way or marking the whole DIV as not available for keyboard entry.  Something like `pointer-events: none;` CSS style maybe?